# Performing Binary Threshold on Video

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have tried performing thresholding using opencv python on images. That works completely fine. Below is the code for normal binary thresholding.
[image: ThresholdedImage]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap=cv2.imread('g.jpg',0)
ret, threshold1 = cv2.threshold(cap, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow("ThresholdFrame",threshold1)
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So, what I want is to take video `cap=cv2.VideoCapture(video2.avi)` and perform background subtraction using `subtractor = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(varThreshold=50, detectShadows=False)`. 
[[image: Screenshotofvideoafterbackgroundsubtraction]]

After background subtraction, the output which obtained, want to perform binary threshold.
Which is where I am having difficulty in performing the task.
How to go about performing thresholding using video input?
Binary threshold need to be performed on backgroundsubracted video.

Comment: Well, a video just really just a sequence of frames/images, so you should be able to use the image you get from `cv2.imread`, frame by frame and then either render them on screen via `cv2.imshow` or save them to a new video file using `cv2.VideoWriter`. I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: basically i want to peform thresholding on video. this is what basically what i want to do. But my actual work is to peform thresholding after background subtraction @natiiix

Comment: Do you need to reset the frame counter back to the first frame of the video or something like that? You typically use a loop when processing a video to iterate through the individual frames and apply whatever filters you need.

Comment: No. No reset of frame counter. @natiiix wait let me show you the code what i written. and let me know whether it is fine or not

Comment: @natiiix code is
 import cv2
import numpy as np


cap=cv2.VideoCapture('video2.avi')
fgbg=cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=100, varThreshold=50, detectShadows=False)
if(cap.isOpened()==False):
    print('Error')

Comment: while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    #ret,thresh=cv2.threshold(fgbg,127,255,0)
    ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(fgbg, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    if ret==True:
        fgmask=fgbg.apply(frame)
        cv2.imshow("Frame",fgmask)
        cv2.imshow("ThresholdFrame",thresh1)
        k= cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF
        if k==27:
            break

    else:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Comment: @natiiix for which i get error saying 
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(fgbg, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s'